# InDesign Server 5.5 Multiple page sizes in one document

Tags: java, indesign-server

I am able to generate PDF files using InDesign Server 5.5. Now I wish to be able to generate a PDF file whose pages vary in size i.e. one page is A4 while another is A5. I can't seem to find the right attribute to set because the setting of the page size is done at the document level instead of page level that is why I can only set the page size of the entire document and not the page size of each individual page. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

[EDIT] I tried creating a new master page and calling setAppliedMasterPage on the pages that I intend to modify the page size. However, I still can't find the right method to call on the MasterPage object to change its dimensions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am still unable to find a solution to this problem. You may still answer if you want. :) The approach I did was to create different PDF files w/ different page sizes and then merge them using PDFBox.